# Vue child component not rerending after parent component's data value updates

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I am trying to have a child component update its props that were passed from the parents at the start of the rendering. Since the value is coming from a fetch call, it takes a bit of time to get the value, so I understand that the child component will receive a 'null' variable. But once the fetch call is completed, the value is updated but the child component still has the original null value.

During my search for a solution, I found that another way was to use Vuex Stores, so I implemented it with the `count` variable and had a button to call a commit and later dispatch with an action function to the store to increment it's value but when the increment happens, it doesn't show the new value on the screen even though with console logs I confirmed it did change the value when the function was called.

I guess I don't fully understand how to update the value of a variable without reassigning it within it's own component or having to call a separate function manually right after I change the value of a data variable.

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div id="banner">
     <div>Title</div>
    </div>

    <p>count: {{count}}</p> // a small test i was doing to figure out how to update data values
    <button @click="update">Click </button>

    <div id="content" class="container">
      <CustomDropdown title="Title Test" :valueProps="values" /> // passing the data into child component

    </div>

  </div>
</template>
<script>
import CustomDropdown from './components/CustomDropdown.vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    CustomDropdown,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      values: null
      count: this.$store.state.count
    }
  },
  methods: {
    update() {
      this.$store.dispatch('increment')
    }
  },
  async created() {
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/getIds", {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
              }
    });
    const data = await response.json();
    this.values = data // This is when I expect the child component to rerender and show the new data. data is an array of objects
    console.log("data", data, this.values) // the console log shows both variables have data
  }
}
</script>
```

CustomDropDown.vue

```
<template>
    <div id="dropdown-container" class="">
        <b-dropdown class="outline danger" variant="outline-dark" :text="title" :disabled="disabled">
            <b-dropdown-item
                v-for="value in values"
                :key="value.DIV_ID"
                href="#">
                {{value.name}}
            </b-dropdown-item>
        </b-dropdown>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    name: 'CustomDropdown',
    components: {},
    props: {
        title: String,
        valuesProp: Array,
        disabled: Boolean
    },  
    data() {
        return {
            values: this.valuesProp
        }
    },
    methods: {
    },
    created() {
        console.log("dropdown created")
        console.log(this.valuesProp) //Always undefined
    }
}
</script>
```

store.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
    state() {
        return {
            count: 0,
            divisionIds: []
        }
    },
    mutations: {
        increment (state) {
            console.log("count", state.count)
            state.count++
        }
    },
    actions: {
        increment (state) {
            console.log("count action", state.count)
            state.commit('increment')
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 3):

One thing you can do is to use a v-if in your child component to only render it after you get your result from you api.

It would be something like:

```
<CustomDropdown title="Title Test" :valueProps="values" v-if="values"/>
```

This way you would make sure that your child component gets rendered only when values are available.

It would only be a bad solution if this api call took so long and you needed to display the child component data to the user before that.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing for now, but I feel there could be a better way? Like an example of an edge case would be if the values in the select box kept changing depending on if a user clicked a certain button

Comment: In this case it would be better to use watch, as Terry answered below.

Comment: as Meeran Khan* answered above*

Answer (score 2):

`data` in your child component `CustomDropdown.vue` is not reactive: therefore the value of `this.values` is not updated when the prop changes. If you want to alias a prop, use computed instead:

```
export default {
    name: 'CustomDropdown',
    components: {},
    props: {
        title: String,
        valuesProp: Array,
        disabled: Boolean
    },
    computed: {
        values() {
            return this.valuesProp;
        }
    },
    created() {
        console.log("dropdown created");
    }
}
```

If you want to console log the most updated values of `this.valuesProp`, you will need to watch it: the same if you want for `this.values`.

Comment: I did this and returned the computed function in the template but it still doesn't render when the new data comes in. Is that how you use it?

Answer (score 1):

Hey you can simply watch it your child component
`watch: {  valuesProp: function(newVal, oldVal) { // watch it if(newVal.length > 0) do something }`
it will watch for the value changes and when you get your desired value you can perform whatever hope it will help you you dont need store or conditional binding for it.

Comment: i think Thalys Menezes refered to my answer using watch not terry's because this is how it will be done @efoc